# Указатели при работе с файлами. Проблема с объектами пользовательского класса

Tags: c++

По этому коду я уже задавал вопрос. Возникли новые ошибки.
Я просто не понимаю, что и как мне нужно исправить...

Пытаюсь создать класс, в котором будут описаны методы для работы с текстовыми файлами: чтение, редактирование, запись и так далее.

Так как методы этого класса хочу использовать в последующих проектах, то делаю это с использованием заголовочных файлов.

**Листинг хиддера MyClasses.h**

```
#ifndef MYCLASSES_H_INCLUDED
#define MYCLASSES_H_INCLUDED
#include <fstream>

using namespace:: std;

class MyClass{

private:

    int string_size=0;      

    char input_symbol=0;    

public:

    int check_line_float(ifstream*);

};

#endif // MYCLASSES_H_INCLUDED
```

**Листинг источника к хиддеру MyClasses.cpp**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "MyClasses.h"

using namespace::std;

int check_line_float(ifstream *input_file){

     int string_size = 0;   

     int error_cnt = 0;

     char input_symbol=0; 

     if(!input_file->is_open()){

       cout << "Cant open file" << endl;

    }else{

        while(*input_file>>noskipws>>input_symbol){

            if (input_symbol != '0' &&
                input_symbol != '1' &&
                input_symbol != '2' &&
                input_symbol != '3' &&
                input_symbol != '4' &&
                input_symbol != '5' &&
                input_symbol != '6' &&
                input_symbol != '7' &&
                input_symbol != '8' &&
                input_symbol != '9' &&
                input_symbol != '.' &&
                input_symbol != 32  &&
                input_symbol != 2   &&
                input_symbol != '-'){

                    error_cnt++;

                    cout << "Incorrect input numeric format. Some unknown symbol is detected" << endl;

                    cout << input_symbol << endl;

                    return -1;

                }

                string_size++;
            }

            cout << "Everething is ok" << endl;

            return 0;

        }

 };
```

**Листинг основной программы The_Matrix.cpp**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "MyClasses.h"


using namespace::std;

int main(){

    MyClass MyObject;

    ifstream input_file("The_Matrix.txt");

    cout<<MyObject.check_line_float(&input_file);

return 0;
}
```

**Информация с окна ошибок**

```
=== Build: Debug in The_Matrix (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|

...\MyClasses.h|11|warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11|
...\MyClasses.h|13|warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11|
...\MyClasses.cpp||In function 'int check_line_float(std::ifstream*)':|
...\MyClasses.cpp|59|warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]|
obj\Debug\The_Matrix.o||In function `main':|
...\The_Matrix.cpp|15|undefined reference to `MyClass::check_line_float(std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char|
error: ld returned 1 exit status|

=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 3 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 15 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: Читать по одной, вникать, о чем речь, и исправлять. Начинаем с первой (бывает так, что одна ошибка тянет за собой еще 150, так что лучше всегда начинать с первой...). Что непонятно тут? **non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11**

Comment: Как я понял, здесь написано, что объявление динамических переменных доступно только в версиях с++11 или gnu++11. Но я не знаю, как иначе мне создать метод, в который я смогу "загонять" любой текстовый файл, используя этот метод в любом проекте. Только используя адресацию. Кстати, я не понял так же, почему указатель здесь именуется не статической переменной. Но да ладно, это видимо не по теме вопрос.

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `int string_size = 0;` инициализировать их в конструкторе класса `MyClass` (old school ;) `MyClass::MyClass() : string_size(0), ...`

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло...

Comment: Но первых предупреждений уже нет? Вы уже включили опцию "компилировать как C++11", или как там она в gcc именуется? Если да - давайте, что там следующее...

Comment: Спасибо за комментарии! Ответ о линковке ниже разрешил вопрос! @Harry я использую Code::Blocks. В  `Global Compiler Settings`  установил галочки напротив `Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard` если именно это имелось в виду. Больше не нашел схожего с  "компилировать как C++11"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предупреждения: 
1 и 2 - инициализируются нестатичные поля класса в описании класса;
3 - в методе `int check_line_float(ifstream *input_file)` в первом блоке ветвления (`if(!input_file->is_open())`) нет `return` или `throw`, - не стоит так делать (методу с возвращаемым типом следует что-то вернуть или бросить исключение).

Ошибка: Ошибка линковки, линковщик не смог найти метод-член класса `MyClass::check_line_float(ifstream *input_file)`.
Вы вызываете метод, который объявлен, но не определен. В файле MyClasses.cpp реализован какой-то метод `check_line_float`, который не является членом какого-либо класса. Чтобы реализовать объявленный метод класса, нужно сделать это через оператор разрешения области видимости "`::`", вот так:

```
//...
int MyClass::check_line_float(ifstream *input_file)
{
    // do smth
}
//...
```

`MyClass::` означает, что вы имеете ввиду именно этот метод-член класса.

Comment: Спасибо! Совет ценный!